# Ротация логов Apache. FreeBSD

Tags: apache, логирование, freebsd

Решил я тут логи апач в ротацию всунуть, добавил в `/etc/newsyslog.conf`

```
/var/log/httpd-access.log               644  3     *    $M1D0 JC
/var/log/httpd-error.log                644  3     *    $M1D0 JC
/var/log/httpd-ssl_request.log          644  3     *    $M1D0 JC
```

И вот наступил сей страшный день, когда `/var/log/httpd-access.log` в ротацию не ушел.

Пробовал так:

```
/var/log/httpd-access.log               644  3     *    $M1D0 JC    # newsyslog
/var/log/httpd-access.log root:wheel    644  3     100  $M1D0 JC    # newsyslog
/var/log/httpd-access.log root:wheel    644  3     100  $M1D0 JC    /var/run/httpd.pid    # newsyslog
/var/log/httpd-access.log root:wheel    644  3     100  $M1D0 JC    /var/run/httpd.pid 30    # newsyslog
```

Ничего не помогает.

Как настроить правильно?

Answer (score 1):

у меня в /etc/newsyslog.conf:

```
/var/log/httpd-access.log               600  7     25000 *    ZC/var/log/httpd-error.log                600  7     10000 *    ZC
```